# How to delete an item from a generic list

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a generic list

How do I remove an item?

EX:

```
Class Student
{
    private number;
    public Number
    {
        get( return number;)
        set( number = value;)
    }

    private name;
    public Name
    {
        get( return name;)
        set( name = value;)
    }

    main()
    {
        static List<student> = new list<student>();

        list.remove...???
    }
}
```

Comment: This is completely off topic, but also consider looking at auto-implemented properties.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Answer (score 25):

Well, there is nothing to remove because your list is empty (you also didn't give it an identifier, so your code won't compile).  You can use the `Remove(T item)` or `RemoveAt(int index)` to remove an object or the object at a specified index respectively (once it actually contains something).

Contrived code sample:

```
void Main(...)
{
    var list = new List<Student>();
    Student s = new Student(...);
    list.Add(s);

    list.Remove(s); //removes 's' if it is in the list based on the result of the .Equals method

    list.RemoveAt(0); //removes the item at index 0, use the first example if possible/appropriate
}
```

Comment: You should use `.RemoveAt(0)` to remove something based on the index number `.Remove(0)` wouldn't work.

Answer (score 17):

From your comments I conclude that you read student name from input and you need to remove student with given name.

```
class Student {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public Student (string name, int number)
    {
        Name = name;
        Number = number;
    }
}


var students = new List<Student> {
    new Student ("Daniel", 10),
    new Student ("Mike", 20),
    new Student ("Ashley", 42)
};

var nameToRemove = Console.ReadLine ();
students.RemoveAll (s => s.Name == nameToRemove); // remove by condition
```

Note that this will remove all students with given name.

If you need to remove the first student found by name, first use `First` method to find him, and then call `Remove` for the instance:

```
var firstMatch = students.First (s => s.Name == nameToRemove);
students.Remove (firstMatch);
```

If you want to ensure there is only **one** student with given name before removing him, use `Single` in a similar fashion:

```
var onlyMatch = students.Single (s => s.Name == nameToRemove);
students.Remove (onlyMatch);
```

Note that `Single` call **fails** if there is not exactly one item matching the predicate.

Comment: @OP: Just remember that removing a Student by name would be stupid in a real-world application because the StudentName will not be unique so chances are you would remove the wrong Student.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
students.Add(new Student {StudentId = 1, StudentName = "Bob",});
students.RemoveAt(0); //Removes the 1st element, will crash if there are no entries
```

OR to remove a known Student.

```
//Find a Single Student in the List.
Student s = students.Where(s => s.StudentId == myStudentId).Single();
//Remove that student from the list.
students.Remove(s);
```

Comment: Grateful
Is already the list is filled.
Student numbers are taken from the input and I remove from the list.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't under stand what you're after. I've update my answer above a little more.

Comment: list<student> lst=new list<student>();

Comment: obj.number = "101"; obj.name= "AA"; lst.add(obj);

Comment: i check the cod. what the students?

Comment: "students" is the list of students you created (you have called it "lst" above)

Comment: error: A local variable named 's' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 's', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: Change it to - Student student = students.Where(s => s.StudentId == myStudentId).Single();

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't give your list a name, and some of your syntax is wonky.

```
void main()
{
   static List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();
}

// later
void deleteFromStudents(Student studentToDelete)
{
   studentList.Remove(studentToDelete);
}
```

There are more remove functions detailed here: [C# List Remove Methods](http://dotnetperls.com/list-remove)

Comment: I think you forgot `void` s. Also, in C# method names are usually capitalized.

Comment: @gaearon - Well, yes... this was for demonstration purposes though.

Answer (score 1):

int count=queue.Count;

```
        while(count>0)
        {
            HttpQueueItem item = queue[0];
            /// If post succeeded..
            if (snd.IsNotExceedsAcceptedLeadsPerDayLimit(item.DataSaleID, item.AcceptedLeadsPerDayLimit) && snd.PostRecord(item.DataSaleDetailID, item.PostString, item.duplicateCheckHours, item.Username, item.Password, item.successRegex))
            {
                if (item.WaitTime > 0)
                    Thread.Sleep(item.WaitTime);
                queue.Remove(item);
            }
                ///If Exceeds Accepted leads per day limit by DataSale..
            else if (!snd.IsNotExceedsAcceptedLeadsPerDayLimit(item.DataSaleID, item.AcceptedLeadsPerDayLimit))
            {
                queue.RemoveAll(obj => obj.DataSaleID == item.DataSaleID);
            }
                /// If Post failed..
            else //if (!snd.PostRecord(item.DataSaleDetailID, item.PostString, item.duplicateCheckHours, item.Username, item.Password, item.successRegex))
            {
                queue.Remove(item);
            }
            count = queue.Count;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete a row or record from generic list in grid view, just write this code-

```
List<Address> people = new List<Address>();
Address t = new Address();
people.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
grdShow.EditIndex = -1;
grdShow.DataSource = people;
grdShow.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `Dictionary<string, Student>` instead of the `List<Student>`.

When you add a Student, add its ID or Name or whatever can uniquely identify it. Then you can simply call `myStudents.Remove(myStudentId)`

Comment: Please check example (Number student is Key)

Comment: I think that we need to think about the actions of using a Dictionary in this scenario - constructions of a dictionary is slow and insert, update and removal means a hadh having to be generated and stored making it slower than List<T>. But for retrieval purposes Dictionaries can be more effective as there is a unique value to search on

Answer (score 0):

Try linq:

```
  var _resultList = list.Where(a=>a.Name != nameToRemove).Select(a=>a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a program that contains 7 cards, then shuffle and I hope to take in order to help them

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random(); 
        var cards = new List<string>();
        //CARDS VECRTOR
        String[] listas = new String[] { "Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3", "Card 4", "Card 5", "Card 6", "Card 7"};


        for (int i = 0; i<= cards.Count; i++)
        {

            int number = random.Next(0, 7); //Random number 0--->7


            for (int j = 0; j <=6; j++)
            {
                if (cards.Contains(listas[number])) // NO REPEAT SHUFFLE
                {

                    number = random.Next(0, 7); //AGAIN RANDOM

                }
                else
                {
                    cards.Add(listas[number]); //ADD CARD
                }
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine(" LIST CARDS");

        foreach (var card in cards)
        {
            Console.Write(card + " ,");


        }

        Console.WriteLine("Total Cards: "+cards.Count);

        //REMOVE

        for (int k = 0; k <=6; k++)
        {
           // salmons.RemoveAt(k);
            Console.WriteLine("I take the card: "+cards.ElementAt(k));
            cards.RemoveAt(k); //REMOVE CARD
            cards.Insert(k,"Card Taken"); //REPLACE INDEX
            foreach (var card in cards)
            {
                Console.Write(card + " " + "\n");

            }


        }


        Console.Read(); //just pause

    }



}
```