# List Remove Item

Tags: c#

I have this following Codes for adding a value in my List.

```
public class Temp  {
     public object Id { get; set; }
     public object Amount { get; set; }
     public object TrasactionDateTime { get; set; } 
    }  

private List<Temp> list = new List<Temp>();
```

Adding

```
list.Add(new Temp{ Id = GetData["Id"], Amount = GetData["Amount"],      TrasactionDateTime = GetData["TransactionDateTime"] });
```

How do i remove and item in the list?

example

```
list.Remove(Id = "1");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete item from generic list in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903893/delete-item-from-generic-list-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the item from the List with `Id = "1"` and then remove it.

```
var item = list.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.Id.ToString() == "1");
if(item != null)
    list.Remove(item);
```

You can also remove the item based on the index using [`List<T>.RemoveAt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx)

Comment: Or use `RemoveAll` which takes a predicate to specify the element(s) to remove.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen, You are right, I thought the OP wants to remove a single item,

Comment: +1: I should agree, that if it's known that list contains only one item with certain `Id`, then walking through the whole list with `RemoveAll` would be unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx)

> The first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified
>   predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T.

```
List<Temp> list = new List<Temp>();
var f = list.Find(c => c.Id == 1);
if (f == null) return;
var x = list.Remove(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.RemoveAll(s => s.Id == "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.RemoveAll (s => s.Id == "1"); // remove by condition
```

**Note that** this will remove all temps with given id.

If you need to remove the first temp found by id, first use First method to find him, and then call Remove for the instance:

```
var firstMatch = list.First (s => s.Id == "1");
list.Remove (firstMatch);
```

If you want to ensure there is only one temp with given id before removing him, use Single in a similar fashion:

```
var onlyMatch = list.Single (s => s.Id == "1");
list.Remove (onlyMatch);
```

Note that Single call fails if there is not exactly one item matching the predicate.