# How to delete item from list

Tags: c#, list

How can I remove the added Weapon in the Test class from my List? I have tried things like `weapon.RemoveItems(Weapon)` but that doesn't work.

```
InventorySlot<Weapon> weapon = new InventorySlot<Weapon>();

public Test()
{ 
    weapon.AddItems(new Weapon());
    weapon.RemoveItems();     
}

class InventorySlot<T>
{
    List<T> items = new List<T>();

    public int Count
    {
        get { return this.items.Count; }
    }

    public void AddItems(T item)
    {
        this.items.Add(item);
    }

    public void RemoveItems(T item)
    {
        this.items.Remove(item);
    }

    public T GetItem(int index)
    {
        return items[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: items.Remove(item) should work fine - are you getting any errors?

Comment: [How to delete an item from a generic list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903893/how-to-delete-an-item-from-a-generic-list)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove an item from a list by index or by reference:

```
list.RemoveAt(0);      // removes the first item in the list

list.Remove(myWeapon); // removes the instance myWeapon from the list
```

And using LINQ indirectly:

```
var firstItem = list.First();
list.Remove(firstItem);

var lastItem = list.Last();
list.Remove(lastItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `index` of the item you wish to delete, then try `list.RemoveAt(index);`